# Save all input History in a log file

Tags: history, save

I would like to write some code in my init.m to save all inputs `{In[1],In[2],...In[lastone]}` right before I close the kernel (or exit Mathematica).
Such a script probably should be kernel-specific but I can settle with one log file.

In this way I will be able to review each day's work and assess my productivity. Also I can trace some tweaks I am implementing without the need to remember in which file I did this and that ...

I hope others in SE also would like such an option.

Comment: Can you not do something along the lines of `?? In` and then `Export["this_session.log",%]`? You'd have to not have your `$HistoryLength` changed.

Comment: If you write the file when you've finished you run the risk of not having anything if there is a kernel crash, power loss etc.

Comment: @Ymareth , you are right. So a periodical save would be more suitable right? Using a Dynamic module...

Comment: Crude answer below and I seem to have misread the question and included Out[n] as well.  If not required ignore the setting for $Post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$Epilog := PutAppend[DateList[], DownValues[In], "log.log"]
```

will do what you want. It assumes the log file exists and will append to it.

You could also place the `PutAppend` in the file end.m, where $Epilog reads from upon exit.

Comment: SCdV thank you. With DownValues[In] i get a list {HoldPattern[In[1]] :>Input1,HoldPattern[In[3]] :>Input3,....} That is a set of rules and this is nice. How can i obtain instead a list : {Hold[Input1],Hold[Input2],....} ?

Comment: @tchronis `DownValues[In] /. RuleDelayed[_, b_] :> Hold[b]`, or, if you just want to see the text of your input without Hold interfering: `DownValues[In] /. RuleDelayed[_, b_] :> HoldForm[b]`

Comment: SCdV thank you. Unfortunately the `$Epilog` value is not working. I have to manually run the command. I inserted it in my init.m file and asking ??$Epilog it outputs correctly `Epilog:=({DateList[],DownValues[In]/. (_:>b_):>HoldForm[b]}>>>$UserDocumentsDirectory<>/mathematica.log)` but when exiting Mathematica (through the frontend) it is not logging...

Comment: @tchronis I have tested it using `Exit[]` to kill the kernel, the log file was indeed created. Did you create the logfile manually first (as mentioned in the answer)?

Comment: Thank you! I tested using Exit[] inside the notebook and it worked. I would prefer though when closing the Mathematica FrontEnd (which closes the kernels) automatically to have the log file Appended. Is this possible?

Comment: @tchronis I tried placing the exit code in end.m.This works with `Exit[]` or `Quit[]`,but not with `File>Exit`, which IMHO goes against the docs: "Mathematica will continue in its main loop until you explicitly tell it to exit. Most Mathematica interfaces provide special ways to do this. Nevertheless, you can always do it by explicitly calling Exit or Quit. Mathematica allows you to give a value to the global variable $Epilog to specify operations to perform just before Mathematica actually exits. In this way, you can, for example, make Mathematica always save certain objects before exiting. "

Comment: @tchronis If you don't mind that the log will be written whenever a window gets closed (including when quiting Mathematica, what we want) then `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 FrontEndEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> (EXITCODE)}]` could work for you.

Comment: SCdV thank you this is asymptotically close to what i need!

Answer (score 1):

This is a little raw but something along the lines of this should work...

```
stream = OpenWrite["C:\\Temp\\KitchenSink.math"];    
$Pre = (Write[stream, #]; #) &;  $Post = (Write[stream, #]; #) &;
```

When finished...

```
Clear[$Pre, $Post]
```