# autocomplete or forward search input histories

Tags: front-end, history

I think there are many bash users here. In bash, a forward search of input histories can be done by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, which let you edit your previous similar input and reuse it. Is there a similar function in *Mathematica*.

Similarly, in *Matlab*, there is a history panel to access the history commands, and the command can also be autocompleted by <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd>.

All these completions are able to search through history sessions, not only the current session.

Following are related questions I find:

[Obtain input expression from history without evaluating](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15512/obtain-input-expression-from-history-without-evaluating)

[Save all input History in a log file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37422/save-all-input-history-in-a-log-file)

Comment: Ctrl+r in bash is actually a **reverse** search